# Storing Series into a pandas DataFrame cell using apply

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a function that returns a Series.  I apply the function to my DataFrame using apply(), and I would like to store the resulting Series into a new column of the dataframe. e.g.,

```
   | 1 |                  2
---+---+------------------------------------
 0 | 1 | <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
 1 | 2 | <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
 2 | 3 | <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

However, it seems that pandas wants to expand the series and store it into multiple columns, so I get a ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({1: [1, 2, 3]})


def f(x):
    return pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'])

df[2] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

How should deal with this?

Comment: it seems that you can do it with `df[2] = [f(x) for x in df[1]]` but I'm not sure having a series in a cell of a dataframe is really a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Ben, yours seems closer to the answer because it still uses f() to generate the series, but why is this a bad idea?

Comment: see the comment of @Kyle under the answer of W-B.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend you save `series` into dataframe cell , but here is one way convert to object

```
df['2']=[pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'])]*len(df)
```

Comment: Thanks W-B, Is there a particular reason not to save a series into a dataframe?

Comment: All the optimizations and advantages you get from pandas are lost if you have object type columns. You might consider using multindex for your column names if you want to logically group related columns.

Comment: Thanks @Kyle, that's helpful.  In this case, the need (or at least want) to store the series in the dataframe is a temporary one, as it gets transformed to something else a step later.

Comment: Then I'd suggest storing as an independent Series or list.